# Unifrom absolute continuity on sequence of measure, $\mathscr{L}_p$ convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Theorem** *Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions of $\mathscr{L}_p$ and 
$v_n(E)=\int_E|f_n|^pd\mu,\:\:\:\:(E\in\mathscr{F},n=1,2...)$.
$\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in pth mean if and only if $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in measure and the family $\{v_n\}$ of measures is equicontinuous at $\emptyset$ 
**Proof**: Suppose first that $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in pth mean. Then by theorem 7.4 $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in measure. For each $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that $\int|f_n|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2^{p+1}}\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:\:n\geqslant N$
Now suppose $\{B_k\}$ is a sequence of sets of $\mathscr{F}$ decreasing to $\emptyset$ Since $\{v_n\}$ is absolutely continuous for $n=1,2...N)$ we can find, by theorem 5.6 an integer $K_0$ such that $\int_{B_k}|f_n|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2^{p+1}}\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:\:k\geqslant k_0\:\:n=1,2...N).$
By (7.3.1) we obtain, for $n\geqslant N_0\:\: k\geqslant k_0$
$\int_{B_k}|f_n|^pd\mu\leqslant 2^p\int_{B_k}|f_N|^pd\mu+2^p\int_{B_k}|f_n-f_N|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\int_{\Omega}|f_n-f_N|^pd\mu<\epsilon$
so that the sequence $\{v_n\}$ is equicontinuous at $\emptyset$.
In other direction, since we assume that $\mu$ is $\sigma-\text{finite}$ on $\Omega$ there must be a sequence $\{E_n\}$ in $\mathscr{F}$
 which decreases to the $\emptyset$ and is such that $\mu(\Omega-E_n)$ is finite for all $n$. Given $\epsilon>0$, the equicontinuity of $\{v_n\}$ now ensures that there is a set $E=E_N$ with $\mu(\Omega-E_n)<\infty$ and 
$\int_E|f_n|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2^{p+2}}\:\:\:\text{for all}\:n$
Thus , for all $m$,$n$, by (7.3.1)
$\int_E|f_n-f_m|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$     (7.3.2)
Now put $\Omega-E=F$,$\mu(F)=\lambda$. By the lemma, the sequence $\{v_n\}$ of measures must be uniformly absolutely continuous. We can therefore find $\eta>0$ such that, for $B\in\mathscr{F},\mu(B)<\eta$
$v_n(B)=\int_B|f_n|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2^{p+3}}$.      (7.3.3)
For each $m,n$ put 
$C_{m,n}=\{x:|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\geqslant\frac{\epsilon}{4 \lambda}^{\frac{1}{p}}\}$
Then 
$\int_{F-C_{m,n}}|f_n-f_m|^pd\mu\leqslant\frac{\epsilon}{4\lambda}\mu(F-C_{m,n})\leqslant\mu(F)=\frac{\epsilon}{4}$.
Since $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in pth mean we can find an $n_0$ such that $\mu(C_{m,n})<\eta$ for $m\geqslant n_0,n\geqslant n_0$. This gives, by (7.3.3),
$\int_{C_{m,n}}|f_n-f_m|^pd\mu\leqslant 2^p\int_{C_{m,n}}|f_n|^pd\mu+ 2^p\int_{C_{m,n}}|f_m|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$,
so that
$\int_{F}|f_n-f_m|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:\:n,m\geqslant n_0$.
This together with (7.3.2) gives
$\int_{\Omega}|f_n-f_m|^pd\mu<\epsilon\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:\:n,m\geqslant n_0$.
$\blacksquare$*

**1**Does not the following expression already proves the theorem "for $n\geqslant N_0\:\: k\geqslant k_0$

$\int_{B_k}|f_n|^pd\mu\leqslant 2^p\int_{B_k}|f_N|^pd\mu+2^p\int_{B_k}|f_n-f_N|^pd\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\int_{\Omega}|f_n-f_N|^pd\mu<\epsilon$"

Is the rest of the proof intended to prove convergence in measure given the $\{v_n\}$ is equicontinuous and there is pth mean convergence?

**2**-  Why  use  the sets $E$,$F$ and $C_{m,n}$ for the proof? What is the intuition behind the use of those sets in the second piece of the proof?

It took me a lot of effort to write this lengthy proof on latex, any incoherencies or mistakes, feel free to report me.Thanks in advance!